# MYSQL count nulls;

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with items and the date that they're added. What I want is to get a report of added items by year and month.

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM items 
GROUP BY YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(items.added)), MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(items.added))
```

The query returns

```
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|       45 |
|       22 |
|        8 |
|       12 |
|       27 |
+----------+
```

which is correct data, but i also want to get `0` from the months when there is no item added for the last 3 years. And also get the column name as `YEAR - MONTH`.

I tried `SELECT IF(COUNT(*) IS NULL, 0, COUNT(*))` and also `SELECT IFNULL(COUNT(*), 0)` but none of them worked. I'm stuck.

Comment: You need a list of all months, if they are not in your table.  A calendar table would be a typical approach.

Comment: can you show your sample data and required output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
--creation of calendar table
create table months(month int);
insert into months values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9), (10), (11), (12);
create table years(year int);
insert into years values (2017),(2018); --here you specify for what years you want to have summary
create table calendarTable(month int, year int);
insert into calendarTable
select month, year from months cross join years;

select ct.year, ct.month, sum(case when i.added is null then 0 else 1) from calendarTable ct
left join items i on ct.year = YEAR(FROM_UNIXTIME(i.added)) and ct.month = MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(i.added))
group by ct.year, ct.month
```

Answer (score 1):

This will work for your condition in mysql workbench.

```
Select ifnull(count(*),0) from [TABLE NAME]
```